# How can I lookup an existing classic load balancer (CLB) via the ARN with the AWS CDK for Python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-elb

`@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2` has [various `from*` lookup methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2/README.html#looking-up-load-balancers-and-listeners), but I don't see anything like that over in [`@aws-cdk/aws-elasticloadbalancing`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancing/README.html). Am I just missing it, or is this really a missing feature?

Thanks!

Edit: For the record, it sounds like this is an unsupported feature. I've filed https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18141 upstream to hopefully get this implemented.

Comment: Side note but why are you using classic load balancers? They're pretty much deprecated

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary for the record, I didn't meant this as a Python specific question. I'd be happy to learn how to do this in typescript, if possible

Comment: As for why we're using classic load balancers: we aren't creating new classic ELBs, but we've taken the stance that we'd like all new infrastructure to be managed via CDK, and sometimes that requires referencing existing infrastructure that was created by hand. That's what I'm trying to do here: set up a new CNAME in Route 53 to point at an existing (very old) classic ELB.

Comment: Ah makes sense - I've answered this question but it may be worth creating a new question for the specific Route 53 use case and pointing out that it isn't possible to lookup. I'm guessing that it just won't be doable via the CDK but someone may have encountered the same problem before. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is a missing feature.**

Other tools like Pulumi (based on Terraform) have been able to do it [via the ARN of the CLB](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/elb/loadbalancer/#look-up).

Terraform itself can do it [via the name of the CLB](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/elb).

---

The docs should be similar across the board but just to double-check this, the [CDK API docs for ELB v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2-readme.html#looking-up-load-balancers-and-listeners) show that you can lookup application load balancers (ALBs) and network load balancers (NLBs) as you've mentioned.

Similarly (to cross out possible language-specific CDK implementations), I looked through the entire [CDK API docs for ELB v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-elasticloadbalancing-readme.html) which refers to classic load balancers (CLBs). There are no lookup methods.

---

Considering Terraform has done this, it means that there must be an AWS API for it - perhaps try seeing if you can use [`AwsSdkCall`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsSdkCall.html) to make a custom call and obtain the data needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, Ermiya!

Is this something worth filing an issue over on GitHub asking for support for this?

Comment: Yes definitely! It's definitely possible so either the CDK has an undocumented method we've missed or they haven't implemented it :) You're welcome.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18141 upstream. We'll see if we get any love 

Comment: @jfly @ me please here when you get any concrete updates :)

Comment: For the record, we got a response: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18141#issuecomment-1003060592. It doesn't sound like this is an intentional ommission because CLB's are deprecated, rather it sounds like it's just an oversight that they encourage you to work around.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to this question. In CDK V2 they have ->

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2-readme.html

This might help:

ApplicationLoadBalancer.fromlookup(options) - Look up an application load balancer.
ApplicationListener.fromLookup(options) - Look up an application load balancer listener.
NetworkLoadBalancer.fromLookup(options) - Look up a network load balancer.
NetworkListener.fromLookup(options) - Look up a network load balancer listener.

Comment: you're talking about AWS's newer load balancers (so-called "Application" Load Balancers). This question is about their older, "Classic" Load Balancers, which are documented on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancing-readme.html.